# Is there any visual relationship between a matrix and its characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

This question is quite contrived and general, but I would like to know if there are *any* interesting visual relationships between a square matrix and its characteristic polynomial. By "any", I mean any image involving a graphical interpretation of a matrix and its characteristic polynomial that makes some sort of visually intuitive sense.

I was surprised to see that searching "characteristic polynomial visualization" online makes it seems as though nobody has thought of this (perhaps this is because it is useless, but it's nice to know anyways).

For example, for any $2\times2$ real square matrix with characteristic polynomial $C_A(\lambda)$, what would the set of points (represented as vectors) $\left\{A[x\space\space C_A(x)]^T,x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ look like on the 2D cartesian plane (basically, we transform every point in the plot of $C_A(\lambda)$ by $A$)?

Given $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}$ and $C_A(\lambda)=\lambda^2-5\lambda-2$, we have
[image]
Where green represents the original plot of $C_A(\lambda)$ and black is the plot of $C_A(\lambda)$ transformed by $A$.

The $2\times2$ identity matrix intuitively does not change its characteristic polynomial graph.

The matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ with $C_A(\lambda)=\lambda^2-2\lambda$ interestingly produces a line which ends abruptly.
[image]

These are just examples, though. The more general question still stands.

Comment: Good question, but I think probably you won't get an answer

Comment: I guess one of the main obstruction is that, to properly understand the characteristic polynomial, we must think of evaluating polynomials with matrices. So, our typical  geometrical intuition of evaluating polynomials by reals aren't helpful altho somehow all the algebraic results are preserved (Vieta's formula)

Comment: Well, why not graphing some examples yourself and find out what they look like?

Comment: @JairTaylor Currently trying to plot out the example I gave using Desmos, but I'm having trouble due to my lack of experience with any graphing software. I'll update my question with an image if I manage to figure it out.

Comment: The graph of the characteristic polynomial will be a parabola, so after this transformation you'll get another parabola where the original zeros (the eigenvalues) have been mapped to points on the line in the direction of the first column of $A$. All parabolas are the same up to scaling/rotating/translation, so I don't think you'll get anything too visually distinct, other than the particular orientation of the image of the parabola.

Comment: @JairTaylor Indeed, you're absolutely correct. I've edited the post to add some images for the given example. I think my original question still stands in the sense that I would like to learn more about these types of visualizations.

Comment: One thing to consider: Eigenvalues and characteristic polynomials are not just properties of matrices, they are properties of linear maps. When dealing with 2D matrices, building the vector $\begin{bmatrix}x\\C_A(x)\end{bmatrix}$ seems a very natural thing to do. But in the world of linear maps, it is not natural at all, requiring an arbitrary choice of basis for the vector space to even accomplish. Thus this approach introduces a level of "artificiality" to the result, making it less likely to provide anything insightful. That does not make it uninteresting, just that it has limits.